# Multiply io.on("connection")

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs, socket.io

After every page updating I have +1 socket connection..

```
module.exports = function(io, client) {
var GameController = {
   gamePage: function(req, res) {
       client.hget('games', 'game.' + req.params.id, function (err, result) {
           if (err) return result(err);
           var game = JSON.parse(result);

           io.on('connection', function (socket) {
               console.log('send');
               console.log(socket.id);
               io.emit('get_bets', game.players);
           });

           res.render('pages/game', {
               title: 'Game - ' + req.params.id,
               user: req.user,
               game: game
           });
       });
   };
return GameController;
});
```

route file:

```
module.exports = function(io, client) {
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();
   var GameController = require('controllers/GameController')(io, client); 
   router.get('/:id', GameController.gamePage);
   ...
   return router;
};
```

Client side on react:

```
var Game = React.createClass({
   getInitialState: function() {
     this.socket = io();

     return {
         bets: null
     }
   },
 socketGetBets: function() {
   var that = this;
   this.socket.on('get_bets', function(data) {
       console.log('get bets');
       that.setState({ bets: data });
   });
   this.socket.on('rand', function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });
 },
...
```

But after debug I find what problem not in client side.

app.js file:

```
var socket_io = require('socket.io');

var io = socket_io();
app.io = io;
//route
var game = require('./routes/games')(io, client);
```

bin/www file:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);

var io     = app.io;
io.attach( server );
```

After page updating, io.on("connection") event show me "send" message in console, after second page updating, I have "send" "send", third update - "send" "send" "send" etc. Than Memory leak warning appeared. Console log socked.id show the same value many time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you call `on`, whether it's `io.on` or `socket.on`, you are registering an event handler. This being the case, you probably don't want to be calling `io.on('connection')` inside of a route, as you will register a new connection handler every time that route is accessed. This is why you are seeing cumulative messages being logged in the console.

In fact, you probably don't want to mix express routing with socket functions at all, as they are different protocols and will work independent of each other.

```
// server side

// this should only be called once per connection.
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // handle socket protocol stuff.. fetching server data, sending data
  socket.on('fetch bets', function() {
    // get game.players from server       

    // updating other sockets
    io.emit('get_bets', game.players);
  })
})

app.get('/route', function (req, res) {
  // handle http protocol stuff.. fetching server data, sending data

  // send data back to caller
  res.json(data)
})
```

The same applies to `socket.on` in your client side. It looks like you're adding a new `'get_bets'` event handler everytime you call `socketGetBets`.

Instead you probably want to register that event handler one single time, likely in `componentDidMount` or `componentWillMount`. Also, because a socket connection can be considered global for your application, you can create the connection above your app.

```
// client side

var socket = io()

var Game = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      bets: null
    }
  },
  componentWillMount: function() {
    var that = this
    socket.on('get_bets', function(data) {
      that.setState({ bets: data })
    })
  }
...
```

Comment: Thank's for a great answer!
Also little question: I need to io.emit('fetch bets') on client side to get access io.emit('get_bets', game.players); on server side?

Comment: How can I get redis data after io.on('connection', function (socket) if I don't have access to req param: 'game.' + req.params.id?

Comment: Often I'll prefix my socket events to help me think what's coming from where. `socket.emit('client:fetch bets')`, which on server would be `socket.on('client:fetch bets')` and vice versa. And the `req.params.id` is already coming from the client right? It's in the url so just send that along with your socket emit. `socket.emit('client:fetch bets', { id: 'whatever' })`

Comment: I have a little gaming app that uses socket + react, if you want to take a look at what i'm doing https://github.com/zen-games/lobby

Comment: Can I get req.params.id in react without other libs or frameworks?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The ID that you are sending along with your HTTP request is already coming from the client side, so instead of sending it as an HTTP request (like a page change) just send it as part of the data object in your socket.emit

Comment: Okey, what the better way to get this id on react client: from url or store somewhere? I try to find method for getting url param in react, but didnt find usefull info

Comment: Where is the id being generated now? In react-router config or something? by clicking a Link or what?

Comment: I don't use react-router lib. Yes, by clicking a link and then redirect to the game page.

Comment: Is this causing a hard refresh? How are you redirecting exactly? Can you post the url of the link?

Comment: Here is my link: /game/56a01975b687177b1f441536
and I think, to create other id in mongo, to minimize this huge _id

Comment: You can override your link behaviour to send that id in your socket.emit, and subsequently navigate using window.location. Shouldn't that work?

Comment: I'll try now, but it only once method to achieve this?